# predicting interarrival poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

Is there any approach or mathematical formula using which we can predict the interarrival times for a Poisson distribution (not the expected interarrival time as it comes out to be same dependent only the rate parameter) ?
Do we need require to know the probability distribution for finding the time interval for a a particular number of events to occur ?

Comment: This is the exponential distribution, or do you mean something else?

Comment: say an event occurred at instant t. now how much time do i have to wait  before the event will occur again.

Comment: Exponential distribution, clearly with parameter 1/λ where λ is the rate (mean) of your poisson distribution

Comment: this is the expected time interval for the event to occur and thus would always be the same if λ is constant. But, since the waiting time follows the exponential distribution, is there any method to determine the exact distribution?

Comment: Please do not use the tag (poisson-geometry) for questions related to Poisson processes or Poisson random variables. These are unrelated.